# I want the main method to print out the value x, which is returned by running threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I want the main method to print out the value x, which is returned by running threads. How can I do it? Hope that my question makes sense.

```
  import java.*;

  public class ServerStudentThread extends Thread 
  {

        public ServerStudentThread(Socket x) {  
       client = x;  
    }

        public void run() 
        {
          //Do something here and return an integer,
          // for example **x**
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
           // ...
           // I want to print out x value here.  
           // But as you can see, x disappears after thread finish its job.
        }
}
```

Comment: At the very least, run() method is unable to return any value. And "main" method in your class is static, so how it is supposed to know about instance variable client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to make x a field in the ServerStudentThread class, not a local variable. then add a method in the class like getValue() that returns x. From the main method, after you create the thread, run it, call the getValue() mehod on the class to print get the value of x and print it.

Comment: After I have x in the main method, I need to compute something and it returns y, how can i put y back to the thread? Sorry for complicating the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: you wil need to add a setY() method in the class, add some field to hold that value, and then you reference that field from the thread.

Comment: I am trying your 1st comment, x returns null because the thread has not finished it job. I want the thread finish first and then get x value in main method. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: if you want one thread (the main one) to wait for another one to finish, you need to call .join() on the thread object from the main method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java 5  there is an Callable Interface.kindly look at this link
http://java-x.blogspot.com/2006/11/java-5-concurrency-callable-and-future.html

> // Code pasted from the link

```
public class CallableTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Callable<Integer> callable = new CallableImpl(2);

  ExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
  Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(callable);

  try {
      System.out.println("Future value: " + future.get());
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

}


public class CallableImpl implements Callable<Integer> {

private int myName;
CallableImpl(int i){
  myName = i;
}

public Integer call() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.println("Thread : " + getMyName() + " I is : " + i);
  }
  return new Integer(getMyName());

}

public int getMyName() {
  return myName;
}

public void setMyName(int myName) {
  this.myName = myName;
}

}
```

Comment: thanks, i am trying this method. It seems to be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should create thread  (call `Thread t = new ServerStudentThread()`, then  call `t.start()` then you should wait until the tread is done. For example call `t.join()`.